# How can I determine if the means between these two small groups are statistically the same?

Tags: r, t-test

Group 1:    0.965116667, 0.972716667, 0.821216667, 0.870816667, 0.816216667

Group 2: 1.046016667, 0.794616667, 0.923416667, 0.927816667, 0.780816667, 0.729616667, 0.710816667, 0.788116667, 0.661316667, 0.750416667, 0.913716667, 1.0147166667

These are numerical data points generated by doing the same experiment in my Biochemistry lab on two different days. How can I conclude if their averages are statistically different from each other?

Would it be appropriate to use equivalence testing? How can I do that?

Can I just do a Welch t test (t.test in R) without testing for Normality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for sharing your data in a convenient format. I will use R to take a careful look at them.

```
x1 =  c(0.965116667, 0.972716667, 0.821216667, 0.870816667, 0.816216667)
x2 =  c(1.046016667, 0.794616667, 0.923416667, 0.927816667, 0.780816667, 0.729616667, 
        0.710816667, 0.788116667, 0.661316667, 0.750416667, 0.913716667, 1.0147166667)

summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.8162  0.8212  0.8708  0.8892  0.9651  0.9727 
var(x1);  sd(x1)
[1] 0.005756155
[1] 0.07586933

summary(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.6613  0.7452  0.7914  0.8368  0.9245  1.0460 
var(x2);  sd(x2)
[1] 0.01545716
[1] 0.1243268
```

There is some difference between the two sample means, but in view of the variability
of the samples, this difference does not seem large enough to be statistically significant.

Stripcharts of these observations show that the values of `x2` (upper plot) extend below
and above those of `x2`. This will make it difficult for any test of location to
find a significant difference in the locations of the two samples.

```
stripchart(list(x1,x2), pch="|", ylim=c(.5,2.5))
```

[image]

Sample sizes are too small for definitive tests of normality, and there is no clear
evidence that the data are not normal. [Shapiro-Wilk tests, done but not shown, do
not reject normality.]

The Welch two-sample t test finds no significant difference in means.

```
t.test(x1,x2)

         Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = 1.0616, df = 12.341, p-value = 0.3087
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.05484864  0.15971531
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.8892167 0.8367833
```

With such small samples, it is no surprise that an F-test finds no
significant difference in variances.

```
var.test(x1, x2)

        F test to compare two variances

data:  x1 and x2
F = 0.37239, num df = 4, denom df = 11, p-value = 0.3529
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.08710826 3.27466010
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
          0.372394
```

None of this 'proves' that the two samples are from the same population, but
I can find no evidence that they are not.

*Notes:* (1) Just as an experiment, suppose you have $n_1 = 5$ observations
from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_1 = .889, \sigma_1=.075)$ and $n_2=12$ from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_2 = .937, \sigma_2=.124),$ where population
parameters roughly match your sample values, you would have only
about 1 chance in 10 of finding a significant difference between
those two samples.  Here is a simulation that estimates the poor power
(around 10%) of such experiments.

```
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(5, .889,.075), 
                            rnorm(12, .837, .124))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .025)
[1] 0.09728
```

(2) Here is a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of your data. It compares
empirical CDFs (ECDFs) of the two samples. It is known to have poor power
for such small sample sizes.

```
ks.test(x1,x2)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x1 and x2
D = 0.58333, p-value = 0.1312
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The $D$-statistic is the maximum vertical distance between the two ECDF plots. The two plots are sufficiently 'entangled' that $D$ is not significantly large.

```
plot(ecdf(x2), col="brown",
     main="ECDF Plots of 2 Samples")
 lines(ecdf(x1), col="blue", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

(3) Other than small sample sizes, I see nothing 'quirky' or 'wrong' with your data.